ChangeStream doesn't include fullDocumentBeforeChange if generated from a replace() OperationType
I have an application which writes data to MongoDB using findOneAndReplacemethod of MongoCollection.
I am trying to configure ChangeStreams on the same to get the FullDocument and FullDocumentBeforeChange.
But I am not receiving FullDocumentBeforeChange even after configuring it like below :
db.watch().
fullDocumentBeforeChange(FullDocumentBeforeChange.WHEN_AVAILABLE)
.fullDocument(FullDocument.WHEN_AVAILABLE) //Or FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP

What could be the reason for this?
I tried to listen to ChangeStreams and have looked at various combinations but nothing seems to be working.
